# Manipulating UArray's in Haskell

Tags: arrays, haskell

I am using some library that uses UArrays.

Currently, the type it returns is `UArray Int Int`.

However, even after going through the [docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.4.0.1/docs/Data-Array-Unboxed.html#t:UArray), it's not immediately clear how I can manipulate these lists. From what I understand `UArray` is an instance of `IArray`, but that doesn't seem to list possible manipulations, either.

I just want to index elements, maybe turn it back into a linked list, but I can't seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just want to index elements, maybe turn it back into a linked list, but I can't seem to figure out how.

It is in the [documentation of
IArrays](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Array-IArray.html):

> `(!) :: (IArray a e, Ix i) => a i e -> i -> e`

> Returns the element of an immutable array at the specified index.

...

> `elems :: (IArray a e, Ix i) => a i e -> [e]`

> Returns a list of all the elements of an array, in the same order as their indices.

---

Regarding

> that doesn't seem to list possible manipulations, either.

note that these are immutable arrays, so you can't really manipulate them much.